# Starting thread within a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have thread pool and I'm executing a task from that thread pool with thread with name `thread-a`
Now within `thread-a` I'm starting a new thread lets call it `thread-child` (might be pooled thread and might not) does this means that `thread-a` is going back to the thread pool when `thread-child` get running? or `thread-a` is going to die?

Comment: Thread a is going to start thread-child and continue executing as normal. There is no 'going back to the pool' Are you using a known implementation of a ThreadPool.

Comment: Yes say for example thread-a is created using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

Comment: That uses [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java) which has workers (they have a thread associated). The workers pull tasks off of a work queue. They don't get removed and replaced in the pool, they're part of the pool, and they pull tasks off of the work queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766009/2987755,
Just adding code in addition to that.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable parentThread = () -> {
    System.out.println("In parentThread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Callable childThread = () -> {
        System.out.println("In childThread : " + 
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(5000); // just to make sure, child thread outlive parent thread
        System.out.println("End of task for child thread");
        return 2; //ignore, no use here
    };
    executorService.submit(childThread);
    System.out.println("End of task for parent thread");
    return 1; //ignore, no use here
};
executorService.submit(parentThread);
Thread.sleep(8000); // wait until child thread completes its execution.
executorService.shutdown();
```

Output:

```
In parentThread : pool-1-thread-1
End of task for parent thread
In childThread : pool-1-thread-2
End of task for child thread
```

Comment: These aren't "end of threads" they should be "end of task." You've submited a task to your executor service, and the task finished. It's up to the service and the threads it created to decide what the life of the thread is.

Comment: @matt, my bad, thanks for pointing out, yes thread and tasks are two different thing.

Answer (score 6):

No. Java does not have an inheritance for threads. All threads are separate and self-sustained. I.e. your **thread-a** will be put back to execution pool. And **thread-child** will be executed until the end (no matter what has happened with **thread-a**) and will NOT be put into execution pool, because it was not created by it.

Comment: Added code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766886/2987755, let me know if I need to correct it.